# Is there a ReLU-like activation function that concatenates positive and negative values?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, relu

Is there a ReLU-like activation function that concatenates positive and negative values? What is its name? Apparently, it doubles the output dimension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems [I have found it](https://medium.com/@danqing/a-practical-guide-to-relu-b83ca804f1f7#:~:text=Concatenated%20ReLU%20has%20two%20outputs,CReLU%20doubles%20the%20output%20dimension). It is called **concatenated ReLU** (CReLU).

> Concatenated ReLU has two outputs, one ReLU and one negative ReLU, concatenated together. In other words, for positive x it produces [x, 0], and for negative x it produces [0, x]. Because it has two outputs, CReLU doubles the output dimension.

- [Understanding and Improving Convolutional Neural Networks via Concatenated Rectified Linear Units](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.05201) (the original paper that introduced CReLU).
- [A TensorFlow implementation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/crelu)

There is also Negative CReLU. It seems that the difference is only the sign.

$$\text{NCReLU}(x) = (\rho(x) , −\rho(−x) )$$